# help with inport csv file to my C# program

Tags: c#, winforms, csv

i try to inport csv file to my database in my C# winform program.

for example the csv file:

```
code  ,name    ,price
101010,computer,200$
```

and i done this:

```
char[] BI = { ',' };
string[] WI = TEMP.Split(BI);
A = WI[0].Trim().ToString();
B = WI[1].Trim().ToString();
C = WI[2].Trim().ToString();
```

but what i can do if the name contain (,) ?

for example

```
code  ,name              ,price
101010,computer 12,200.00,200$
```

if i get this type of csv:

```
code    ,name                ,price
"101010","computer 12,200.00","200$"
```

how to deal with this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx, I believe this solves your problem.

Comment: I use CsvReader when Filehelpers has issues.

Comment: @Scott, what issue would those be, and wouldn't it be best to report them to the author?

Comment: @he_the_great I had some issues with non printable characters in the csv (caused from a export from a corrupted database) i was importing. CSVReader was simpler to dive in to and edit so i could break on the bad lines and skip over them

Answer (score 8):

The best thing to do is not roll your own csv and use a existing free library. I recommend [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/).

EDIT:

Here is a [fun little read](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp), I bet you are on step 2 or step 3.